# Prove that the relation 'is parallel to' on the set 'S' of all straight lines in a plane is an equivalence relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, equivalence-relations, symmetry, relations

Prove that the relation 'is parallel to' on the set 'S' of all straight lines in a plane is an equivalence relation .

My attempt:

The relation 'is parallel to' on set 'S' is:

(1). Reflexive, because every line is parallel to itself.

Comment: What is ... the definition of being parallel?

Comment: @pjs36, what do you want?

Comment: In your attempt, you haven't used the definition of what it means for two lines to be parallel. For symmetry and transitivity, you'll have to use the definition (and it really should have been mentioned when talking about reflexivity). So I figured it would be good to get the definition out of the way (and you may even come up with ideas about the last two parts, as you're thinking about the definition).